# clean text string

Tags: php

I need to remove everything (parentheses, punctuation, etc), using PHP, from a text string and leave just text.

Someone suggested this:

```
$str= trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $str));
```

Also, if there are words like: **Bob's** it needs to be cleaned to **Bob**. I also do not need any numbers, just words separated by commas.

Comment: Do you want to remove just parentheses or also text within them? The code you posted also removes the text inside parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $str);
```

This will replace everything that isn't `A-Z` or `a-z` (i.e., everything that isn't a letter).

Answer (score 0):

The following will replace anything that's not a letter or comma as described in your OP. However, it will not change **Bob's** to **Bob**. If that's what you require, comment back with more examples.

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z,]/', '', $str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this if you want only string from tags and script.

```
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string_data));
```

I think this method will help you to get all text from script or tags it can be used to split individual tag also. like this :

```
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string_data),"<p>");
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string_data),"<a>");
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string_data),"<span>");
```